# Not able to see the simulators in Visual Studio 2022 Windows, after using remote login

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging, macos-ventura, xcode14.3

I do not have a mac, and I used the remote login feature to get into a MAC and tried deploying, but I am not getting an option to select any simulators, basically the list is empty, I tried a couple of things from the internet, but it's not working, although MAUI applications are working perfectly fine.
Xcode 14.3
MacOS Ventura
Xamarin iOS 16.2.0.5

this is what I'm getting
Any inputs would be really helpfull
[image]

Any inputs would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be noted that `Xcode14.3` support is in progress, please see [[META] Xcode 14.3 Support for Xamarin, .NET 6/7 and MAUI · Issue #17561 · xamarin/xamarin-macios · GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561) and follow the progress.

For your scenario, it's recommended that you try reverting back to `Xcode 14.2`. If you still want to keep `Xcode 14.3` and want to go back to the previous version: `Xcode 14.2`, you can download `Xcode 14.2` from [the downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) in the Apple Developer Portal.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've reverted to Xcode 13.3 and it is showing me the options, but before downloading Xcode 14.2, can you please confirm if this version will certainly work, because my internet is dodgy and the downloads are close to 12GB

Comment: @Venky Thanks for the response, I can confirm that Xcode 14.2 will work.